# Difference and names of the arrays

Tags: c, arrays, declaration

What is the difference between array declaration `int *a[20]`, `int a[20]`, `int (*a)[20]`?

What will be their names and how are they applied in programming?
writing *a++ gives error as well as a++ in first two cases while third one doesn't? why?

Comment: It'll be very helpful for you to read a basic tutorial, these topics are the very basic of C programming.

Comment: Sniff Sniff - Sunday - Homework perhaps

Comment: Updating the question and adding additional questions to the existing one leads to more down votes

Comment: Remember 'declaration matches use'.  The declarator (the bit after the `int` in the examples) will produce an `int` when written in code.  It would be easier if the variables had different names.  The first one means that `*a[1]` is an `int`, or `a[1]` is an `int *`.  The second one means that `a[1]` is an `int`.  The third one means `(*a)[1]` is an `int`.  The first two are arrays; you can't increment arrays (arrays are _not_, repeat **not**, pointers — but arrays and pointers are closely related).  The last is a pointer (to an array) and can be changed.

Answer (score 2):

```
int *a[20];
```

`a` is array of 20 pointers

```
int a[20];
```

`a` is array of 20 `int` elements

```
int (*a)[20];
```

`a` is pointer to array of 20 int elements

Edits:

When you have `a++` where `a` is a array then this is equivalent to `a= a + 1;` and as per the below standard array name can't be a modifiable lvalue.

> A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that does not have array type,
>   does not have an incomplete type, does not have a const-qualified
>   type, and if it is a structure or union, does not have any member
>   (including, recursively, any member or element of all contained
>   aggregates or unions) with a const-qualified type.

Answer (score 0):

- int a;                 // An integer
- int *a;               // A pointer to an integer
- int **a;             // A pointer to a pointer to an integer
- int a[10];          // An array of 10 integers
- int *a[10];        // An array of 10 pointers to integers
- int (*a)[10];     // A pointer to an array of 10 integers
- int (*a)(int);     // A pointer to a function a that takes an integer argument and returns an integer
- int (*a[10])(int); // An array of 10 pointers to functions that take an integer argument and return an integer

Examples from RMB Consulting.